# C++ Error char assignment

Tags: c++

**Error in assignment char :**

```
structplusclass.cpp: In constructor ‘Soldado::Soldado(char, unsigned int, char, char, char)’:
structplusclass.cpp:25:27: error: invalid conversion from ‘char’ to ‘const char*’ [-fpermissive]
  strcpy(mTodos.modelo, mol);
                           ^
In file included from /usr/include/c++/5/cstring:42:0,
                 from structplusclass.cpp:2:
/usr/include/string.h:125:14: note:   initializing argument 2 of ‘char* strcpy(char*, const char*)’
 extern char *strcpy (char *__restrict __dest, const char *__restrict __src)
              ^
structplusclass.cpp:27:29: error: invalid conversion from ‘char’ to ‘const char*’ [-fpermissive]
  strcpy(mTodos.material, mat);
                             ^
In file included from /usr/include/c++/5/cstring:42:0,
                 from structplusclass.cpp:2:
/usr/include/string.h:125:14: note:   initializing argument 2 of ‘char* strcpy(char*, const char*)’
 extern char *strcpy (char *__restrict __dest, const char *__restrict __src)
              ^
structplusclass.cpp:28:18: error: invalid conversion from ‘char’ to ‘const char*’ [-fpermissive]
  strcpy(mNome, ns);
```

**Code:**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
#define SIZE 20

using namespace std;

struct faca {
    char modelo[SIZE];
    unsigned int peso;
    char material[15];
};

class Soldado {
    public:
        Soldado (char ns, unsigned int p, char mat, char arm, char mol);
        ~Soldado ();
        void Imprime();
    protected:
        faca mTodos;
        char mNome[SIZE];
        char mArmapri[SIZE];
};

Soldado::Soldado (char ns, unsigned int p, char mat, char arm, char mol) {
    strcpy(mTodos.modelo, mol);
    mTodos.peso = p;
    strcpy(mTodos.material, mat);
    strcpy(mNome, ns);
    strcpy(mArmapri, arm);
}

void Soldado::Imprime () {
    cout << "Soldado : " << mNome << ", " << "firearm : "
     << mArmapri << endl;
    cout << endl << " Faca : " << mTodos.modelo << ", " 
    << "lenght : " << mTodos.peso << ", " << "Material : "
    << mTodos.material << endl;
}

Soldado::~Soldado () {
    mTodos.peso = 0;
}

int main() {
    char names1[SIZE], fire[SIZE];
    char  names2[SIZE], mat[15];
    unsigned int eight;
    cout << "nome Soldado, nome arma de fogo " << endl;
    cin >> names1 >> fire;
    cout << "modelo faca e material " << endl;
    cin >> mat >> names2;
    cout << "peso" << endl;
    cin >> eight;
    Soldado brazil(names1, eight, mat, fire, names2);
    brazil.Imprime();



    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Do you understand differences between `const char*`, `char[]` and `char`? It seems it is right time to read some good book for beginners.

Comment: Normally you should be scraping it all and moving to std::string as fast as you can. Is this some kind of school assignment where you are not allowed to use parts of the standard library?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Soldado::Soldado() takes the wrong parameters.

```
char names1[SIZE], fire[SIZE];

cout << "nome Soldado, nome arma de fogo " << endl;
cin >> names1 >> fire;

Soldado brazil(names1, ..., ..., fire, ...);
```

Here `names1` and `fire` are both declared as type `char[SIZE]`. What this means is that there are `SIZE` items of type `char` sitting in a row in memory (specifically, on the stack, but that isn't critical to know for this). But then you pass these on to your constructor, and your constructor is expecting this:

```
Soldado::Soldado (char ns, ..., ..., char arm, ...) { ... }
```

Here, `ns` and `arm` are declared as type `char`, which is a single item of type `char` rather than a list of them like above.

The best easy fix to this problem would be to change `ns` and `arm` (as well as the other parameters that are expecting words) from type `char` to `char[SIZE]`. This will correct your compiler error, and get your code working.

However, there is a little bit more. Your constructor has a few lines like this:

```
strcpy(mTodos.modelo, mol);
```

These will work perfectly fine as long as your user never types a name longer than 19 letters long (leaving one `char` to mark the end). But if they do type a longer name, your code will happily write past the end of the memory you have reserved for it. You should protect your memory with the `strncpy() function like this:

```
strncpy(mTodos.modelo, mol, SIZE);
mTodos.modelo[SIZE - 1] = '\0';
```

Unfortunately, you need that second line to ensure that the string ends in a `null` character since `strncpy()` won't always do it for you.